# "SELECT @@IDENTITY" throws overflow error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am working on an MS Access solution where I need to insert a row and use its ID from within VBA. Thankfully, SQL gave us `@@IDENTITY` for exactly this purpose.

Or so I thought. In practice, it throws an overflow error. What can be possible causes of such an error?

Multiple Google searches could not come up with a solution.

Full line of code:

```
iid = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)
```

German error message:

```
Laufzeitfehler '6': Überlauf
```

Translation:

```
Runtime Error '6': Overflow
```

Comment: Do you perform an insert on the same connection before executing that query?

Comment: @DStanley Yes, I do. It is the line above it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you need to declare iid as a 'variant' instead of an 'integer'?

http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1666779-any-idea-why-i-get-runtime-error-6-overflow.html

Comment: Used the solution by @GordThompson. Thank you!